# A watermark inside a rectangle which filled the certain color

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to add a watermark at a picture. But just a text, but a rectangle filled with the black color and a white text inside it.

For now, I only can put a text:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw

img = Image.open("in.jpg")

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-C.ttf", 66)
#font = ImageFont.truetype("Arialbd.ttf", 66)
draw.text((width - 510, height-100),"copyright",(209,239,8), font=font)
img.save('out.jpg')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will draw the text on a black rectangular background:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

img = Image.open("in.jpg")
width, height = img.width, img.height

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype(
    "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-C.ttf", 66)
x, y = (width - 510, height-100)
# x, y = 10, 10
text = "copyright"
w, h = font.getsize(text)
draw.rectangle((x, y, x + w, y + h), fill='black')
draw.text((x, y), text, fill=(209, 239, 8), font=font)
img.save('out.jpg')
```

[image]

Using imagemagick, a better looking watermark could be made with

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype(
    "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-C.ttf", 66)
text = "copyright"
size = font.getsize(text)
img = Image.new('RGBA', size=size, color=(0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0), text, fill=(209, 239, 8), font=font)
img.save('label.jpg')
```

and then calling (through `subprocess` if you wish) something like

```
composite -dissolve 25% -gravity south label.jpg in.jpg out.jpg
```

[image]

or if you make label with a white background,

```
composite -compose bumpmap -gravity southeast label.jpg in.jpg out.jpg
```

[image]

---

To run these commands from within the Python script, you could use `subprocess` like this:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex

from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

font = ImageFont.truetype(
    "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-C.ttf", 66)
text = "copyright"
size = font.getsize(text)
img = Image.new('RGBA', size=size, color='white')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0), text, fill=(209, 239, 8), font=font)
img.save('label.jpg')

cmd = 'composite -compose bumpmap -gravity southeast label.jpg in.jpg out.jpg'
proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd))
proc.communicate()
```

Comment: how do I run the 2nd and 3rd examples?

Comment: Once you've installed `imagemagick` (on Ubuntu, for example, `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`), then you can either call those commands from the command-line, or incorporate them into the Python script. I've edited the post above to show how.

Comment: and how do I put "label.jpg" to the certain position at an original picture, let's say, at the right-bottom?

Comment: `-gravity southeast` puts `label.jpg` in the right-bottom corner. For more control over the exact position, you could use `-gravity +w+h`, where `(w,h)` is the location where you want the label with respect to an origin in the upper-left corner. For more ideas on watermarking, see [this page on Annotating Images](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#watermarking).

Comment: The first few `import` statements are wrong. It should be `from PIL import xxx` not `import xxx`.  Also the width and height variables come from nowhere.