# Manipulate Image and store at local disk python/django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, image-manipulation

I'm learning django/python.so i'm totally new to django.
i would like to implement image manipulation.

I have some images on my local disk(in media folder) on which  i want to put watermark image(which is image url/web link).

After manipulation i want to store new image on my local folder.
Also,i don't want to store updated new image in database.

Please suggest me any library or ideas which can serve my purpose.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18869365/2662892

Comment: looking like similar.But i want to deal with django media folder.Also have to put requested image on the existing image and store updated image with new image in media folder.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow